# Overflow: scroll not working on my responsive menu. What to do?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

The `overflow: scroll;` property of my responsive menu is not working. I couldn't understand which property/attribute is stopping this from applying.

Following is the Responsive CSS properties for the header:

```
header .menu_icon{
    display: block;
}

ul.social{
    display: none;
}

header nav{
    display: block;
    background: #353434;
    margin: 21px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 1px #2c2c2c solid;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
    overflow: scroll;
}
header nav{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;


}
header nav.show_menu{
    display: block;

}
header nav ul li{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px #2c2c2c solid;

}
header nav ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 0;
}
header nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
header nav ul li a:active{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: #2c2c2c;
}
```

I am adding `overflow: scroll;` in `header nav`. Even I have tried adding this property for every element. It still doesn't works.

Here is the screen shot for my responsive website:
[image]

Comment: dont you have to put scroll on `ul` ??

Comment: and I think you want it only in right side not bootom so use: `overflow-y: scroll !important;` and set `max-height: 100px !important;`

Comment: But the `ul`'s Container is `nav` ? Also, I have tried putting it there too still doesn't work.

Comment: what about my second comment?

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Should I take this question off ?

Comment: no i WILL POST IT AS ANSWER AND THEN VOTE UP AND MARK AS ANSWER

Comment: mark as answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: do you understand how to mark as answer?

Comment: Yes I do, I did it - it wasn't letting me do it for certain period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ADD :**
`overflow-y: scroll !important;` and set `max-height: 100px !important;`